# flash action script 2.0 extracting array items

Tags: actionscript-2

(ActionScript 2 ONLY)

My site is a SWF which loads on user requests data from a MySQL DB via PHP.
I have no problem mastering the whole communication process.

On the Home page, along with News which are already presented in the main right part of the page, I wish to display on the left part some reminders of essential services offered and also mandatory actions registered users must do when visiting the site.

The DB returns: an array with a | delimiter and the total of the array items.

In Flash, I use the following function to get the array:

```
remindersFct = function () {
          var myReminders = new LoadVars();
          myReminders.identity = "reminders";
          myReminders.onLoad = function(ok) {
                    if (ok) {
                                   _root.reminderFld.html = true;
                                   var myArray:Array = new Array(myReminders.mydata.split("|"));
                                   myArray.length = myReminders.totalItems;
                    }
                    else {
                                   stop();
                    }
          };
          myReminders.sendAndLoad("misc.php",myReminders,'POST');
};
remindersFct();//start the process
```

I want to know differents things...:

1 - How can I "explode" this array into its differents items (all of them are strings of text)
2 - Then, how can I tell the SWF to display them, one after another, in the appropriate htmlText field
3 - How can I adjust the duration of each of these items based on the length of the text they contain

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: 1/ The best way to "explode" strings is, as you seem to do : mystring.split. Your line "myArray.length = myReminders.totalItems;" is not ok : .length should be a read-only value automatically set when the string is splitted.

Comment: 2/ If I understand correctly, you should create the textfields one after the other with _root.createTextField... But I'm not sure I understood correctly as I didn't understand step 3 at all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the line you've already listed 
    var myArray:Array = new Array(myReminders.mydata.split("|"));
will explode the strings into an array. As for the display, I would recommend you use a for..in statement so something like

```
for(x in myArray){
    myDynamicTextField.htmlText += (myArray[x] + "<br>");
}
```

Note that since for..in often iterates in reverse, you might want to do myArray.reverse() first.

As for duration, that's a bit tougher nut to crack. The above code puts the text in all at once— You might want instead to set up a counter, and a timer for the number of frames left before the next text insertion, something like:

```
_root.x = 0;
_root.timer = 5; //frames
```

for setup, and then in an onEnterFrame:

```
_root.timer--;
if(_root.timer == 0){
     myDynamicTextField.htmlText += (myArray[_root.x] + "<br>");

     if(_root.x >= myArray.length-1){
        delete this.onEnterFrame; //clean up
     } else {
        _root.timer = ... //put whatever value should go here depending on the length of myArray[_root.x]
     }
     _root.x++;
}
```

Hopefully that should work. Good luck!